# How to upload images in NestJs with GraphQL

Tags: graphql, nestjs

Yesterday i was trying to use this library called [graphql-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-upload) but the problem is that the library graphql-upload has a lot of import issues, and downgrading to previous versions not solving this problem.

What can i use to implement image upload in my NestJs app?

Answer (score 1):

After reading some previous questions I came to the conclusion to use graphql-upload@13.0.0 due to the changes of package in newer versions.

Here is my conclusion:

**main.ts**

```
// Ignore the import error
// @ts-ignore
import { graphqlUploadExpress } from 'graphql-upload';


    async function bootstrap() {
      // Set app to use graphql-upload
      app.use(graphqlUploadExpress({maxFileSize: 1000000, maxFiles: 10 }));
      // Rest of the code
    }
```

**upload.resolver.ts**

```
import { Args, Mutation, Resolver } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { createWriteStream } from 'fs';
// Ignore the import errors
// @ts-ignore
import { GraphQLUpload, FileUpload } from 'graphql-upload';

@Resolver()
export class UploadResolver {
  @Mutation(() => Boolean)
  async singleUpload(
    @Args({ name: 'file', type: () => GraphQLUpload })
    { createReadStream, filename }: FileUpload,
  ) {
    console.log('hello world');

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =>
      createReadStream()
        .pipe(createWriteStream(`./uploads/${filename}`))
        .on('finish', () => resolve(true))
        .on('error', () => reject(false)),
    );
  }
}
```

Create the 'uploads' folder in the root directory;

To test it I use Insomnia. Here is my query settings:

```
operations: { "query": "mutation ($file: Upload!) { singleUpload(file: $file) }", "variables": { "file": null } }

map: { "0": ["variables.file"] }

0: // Your file
```

[image: Here is the reuslt]

Comment: why dont install @types/graphql-upload?

Comment: types are already in the package